# Jupyter Python Markdown: Evaluated Inline code in LaTeX output

Tags: python, latex, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pandoc

*Python Markdown* is a very nice extension for the *jupyter* notebook, which is in turn great for literate programming, i.e. mixing text and code.

*Python Markdown* makes it possible to include short inline code in *Markdown* cells in *Jupyter* like in the following example:

Python cell: `a = 3.1415`

Markdown cell: `The value of a was {{a}}.`

Everything works fine in the browser interface, but when I export it to LaTeX (or PDF via LaTeX), the output will still contain `{{a}}` as an unevaluated expression.
It would of course be really helpful to have the evaluated expression in the output for generating reports.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was actually rather trivial:

When enabling a certain option on the command line, this will create an entry in the web interface irrespective of this option actually exists.
I had mispelled `Python Markdown` with `python-markdown` and ended up with this second entry in the web interface.
Enabling the first entry fixed the problem.
The second entry could be savely removed.